# Artifactory 7.77.5 Cluster join: Retry 5: Service registry ping failed, will retry

Tags: artifactory

I am facing an issue with starting my jfrog artifactory instance. It gets stuck in a long loop of

```
Cluster join: Retry 5: Service registry ping failed, will retry.
```

until it times out.
and when it times out I get this error

```
[jfrt ] [ERROR] [7ab5e09abafc4d74] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:296      ] [jf-common-pool-1    ] - Cluster join: Service registry ping failed; 
2024-02-20T12:14:51.477Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [7ab5e09abafc4d74] [ctoryContextConfigListener:126] [art-init            ] - Application could not be initialized: HTTP response status 404:Failed on executing request. Response: 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
```

Here is my system.yaml and server.xml files which is the only place I have configured things.

```yaml
System.yaml
## @formatter:off
## JFROG ARTIFACTORY SYSTEM CONFIGURATION FILE
## HOW TO USE: comment-out any field and keep the correct yaml indentation by deleting only the leading '#' character.
configVersion: 1

## NOTE: JFROG_HOME is a place holder for the JFrog root directory containing the deployed product, the home directory for all JFrog products.
## Replace JFROG_HOME with the real path! For example, in RPM install, JFROG_HOME=/opt/jfrog

## NOTE: Sensitive information such as passwords and join key are encrypted on first read.
## NOTE: The provided commented key and value is the default.

artifactory:
  port: 8046

## SHARED CONFIGURATIONS
## A shared section for keys across all services in this config
shared:
  ## Java 17 distribution to use
  #javaHome: "JFROG_HOME/artifactory/app/third-party/java"

  ## Extra Java options to pass to the JVM. These values add to or override the defaults.
  #extraJavaOpts: "-Xms512m -Xmx2g"

  ## Security Configuration
  security:
    ## Join key value for joining the cluster (takes precedence over 'joinKeyFile')
    #joinKey: "<Your joinKey>"

    ## Join key file location
    #joinKeyFile: "<For example: JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/security/join.key>"

    ## Master key file location
    ## Generated by the product on first startup if not provided
    #masterKeyFile: "<For example: JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/security/master.key>"

    ## Maximum time to wait for key files (master.key and join.key)
    #bootstrapKeysReadTimeoutSecs: 120

  ## Node Settings
  node:
    #ip: 127.0.0.1
    ## A unique id to identify this node.
    ## Default auto generated at startup.
    #id: "art1"

    ## Default auto resolved by startup script
    #ip:

    ## Sets this node as primary in HA installation
    #primary: true
    #taskAffinity: any
    ## Sets this node as part of HA installation
    #haEnabled: true

  ## Database Configuration
  database:
    

    ## One of mysql, oracle, mssql, postgresql, mariadb
    ## Default Embedded derby

    ## Example for postgresql
    #type: postgresql
    #driver: org.postgresql.Driver
    #url: "jdbc:postgresql://<your db url, for example: localhost:5432>/artifactory"
    #username: artifactory
    #password: password

  #extraJavaOpts: "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

```xml
Server.xml
<!--
  ~ Artifactory is a binaries repository manager.
  ~ Copyright (C) 2019 JFrog Ltd.
  ~
  ~ Artifactory is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
  ~ it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License as published by
  ~ the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
  ~ (at your option) any later version.
  ~
  ~ Artifactory is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  ~ but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  ~ MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
  ~ GNU Affero General Public License for more details.
  ~
  ~ You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License
  ~ along with Artifactory.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
  -->
<Server port="8015" shutdown="BnkmvDuSjyuu">
    <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector port="8046" sendReasonPhrase="false" relaxedPathChars='[]' relaxedQueryChars='[]' maxThreads="200" />

        <Connector port="8091" address="localhost" maxThreads="5" acceptCount="5"  />

        <!-- Must be at least the value of artifactory.access.client.max.connections -->
        <Connector port="8040" sendReasonPhrase="false" maxThreads="50" address="localhost" />



        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
            <Host name="localhost" workDir="/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/work/artifactory/tomcat" appBase="webapps" startStopThreads="3">
                <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve" showReport="false" showServerInfo="false"/>
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>

</Server>
```

I tried killing the running processes that are up when I do

```
ps -ef|grep -i artifactory.sh
```

I tried checking each of the [reserved ports](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/artifactory-network-ports) if they were in use before running artifactory.sh

I tried a clean install of jfrog artifactory with RPM

I tried adding the 8046 port to the system.yaml file as there was an error earlier with some connection refused to 8046 port.

I tried searching other stackoverflow posts but I can't seem to apply their solutions to my problem

Have anyone else faced this issue before and can help?

Comment: JFYI `8046` is default router port. Did you change router port `router.entrypoints.internalPort` in the system.yaml ?

Comment: Can you clarify what OS you are using, and what is the install type of Artifactory (RPM,Debian,Docker)?

I ask, because a number of OS are not supported from 7.77.x, see here: https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-release-information/artifactory-release-notes

Comment: @ALex_hha I havent seen that setting in the system.yaml file but if I remove the line
artifactory:
  port: 8046
i will get the this error instead: 

Cluster join: Retry 5: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access': Connect to localhost:8046 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused

Comment: @DavidLivshin The server is running on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.9 (Ootpa) and I have installed Artifactory with RPM

Comment: You should check access log

Comment: I checked the access log but it seems it only contains older logs from 2 days ago.
Those logs also seems related to the 8046 port
Retry 80 Elapsed 39.21 secs failed: Registration with router on URL http://localhost:8046 failed with error: UNAVAILABLE: io exception. Trying again

Comment: Please remove the custom port, make sure everything is killed, then try again.
You should check artifactory-service.log and access-service.log for original error that occurs before all the retry error messages. If neither of those logs rotate, then check the tomcat directory in the log folder, and see if the tomcat server is throwing errors. Finally, contact support, they are great at helping out!

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the system.yaml you have provided, I can see you have changed the default Artifactory port (8081). While it's allowed to change the port, we need to make sure we don't take ports that are already in use by the different services in the JFrog Platform. You can check the entire used ports [here](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/artifactory-network-ports).

In your case, you changed it to a port that is already in use by the router service.

This also explains the "loop" errors you see. Artifactory is trying to start up but some of the important services are not able to register.